# Redux change multiple states

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, redux

Say I have a global state reducer that has this shape:

**global reducer:**

```
const globalInitialState = {
  userId: 0,
  year: 1900
}
```

Then I have a state reducer for data based upon those global parameters:

**summary reducer:**

*User 10's data for 2018*

```
const summaryDataInitialState = [{data for user 10, 2018}, {data}, {data}];
```

to update the "summary data" I have an async redux-thunk action:

Summary Actions:

```
getSummary = (userId, year) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    let data = await api.getData(userid, year);
    dispatch(success(data));
  }
}
```

But when you change the year globally, how should I trigger updating the summary data?

Should I call the summary action "getSummary" from my "updateYear" action or is this a bad pattern/design?  I don't like how this ties "summaryActions" to the "globalActions".  And further down the road, maybe lots and lots of "sub-state" would need to be changed when these globals are changed. Also, I don't want the intial setting of userId, year to trigger getting all state in the app, I want to retrieve this as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dispatch the reducer type directly and then the reducer will just pick it up without having to directly import the action.

```
getSummary = (userId, year) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    let data = await api.getData(userid, year);
    dispatch(success(data));
    dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_YEARLY', payload: year})
  }
}
```

Or when you dispatch the success the global reducer can also catch the reducer type it dispatches.

summary reducer:

```
SET_SUCCESS: (state, action) => ({...state, year: action.payload.year, userid: action.payload.userid})
```

and then in  global reducer:

```
SET_SUCCESS: (state, action) => ({...state, year: action.payload.year})
```

If they both watch the same type (SET_SUCCESS) then they will both take the dispatch of that action with the payload.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your last sentence?

Comment: See my edit. If you add some more details around your reducers and the success action then I can add a more specific example if it still is not clear

Comment: I understand thanks. It is backwards from what i am thinking - changing the YEAR will trigger updating the summary data (for the YEAR) but I get the idea.  But, is this bad form? It feels like coupling.

Comment: I think it is the most de-coupled you can get in the case you are trying. You could make the argument that if the data is present in the other reducer then you are duplicating data by also putting the value in the other state object. So you could update to only use one of those values in the app or you can combine those values into a single state object since they are tied together. It is a design approach, but I would say it is pretty common for people to call actions/reducers from other files/reducers.

Comment: Ya, maybe the data should be hashed by userid => year => data.  I just don't want to retrieve the whole app data if I change the year, if I'm not on a page with visible data